# Where to look to understand specific combinations of nouns and prepositions?

Tags: word-usage

Native speakers corrected this sentence of mine:

> Die Alterungswelle ist ein Begriff, der bedeutet, dass es eine starke Vergrößerung an ***die*** Alten in der Gesellschaft geben wird.

by eliding the marked "die":

> Die Alterungswelle ist ein Begriff, der bedeutet, dass es eine starke Vergrößerung ***an Alten*** in der Gesellschaft geben wird.

So it appears as if "Vergrößerung an ..." requires the omission of any and all articles even though the German expression for "elderly" is "die Alten".

Now my question is, how can one who is learning German possibly discover this specific fact regarding the use of "an" with "Vergrößerung", and whether this is purely idiomatic or whether it reflects a more general principle of the language? This assumes that it isn't acceptable to simply mimic what these Germans say, since they could be wrong.

Of course, one can go to DWDS and examine the Korpusbelege for similar constructs and look for patterns. But that doesn't really allow for any generalization and limits the understanding to this specific word combination. So any advice regarding where an authoritative explanation should be sought would be appreciated.

Comment: imho, this is just an example of how (or whether) to use articles, and it has less to do with prepositions.

Comment: I have been unable to find any counter examples of "Vergrößerung an ..." with an article, suggesting it does have to do with the noun-preposition combination.

Comment: There are plenty of examples with article, you just have to look it up.  "Vergrößerung an den ... " or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First something about the word "Vergrößerung":

The reason that you don't find any example for "Vergrößerung an ..." is that "Vergrößerung" is just not used with "an" in that way, except maybe in sloppy spoken  language. "Vergrößerung" oder "vergrößern" are used for things that become bigger, and that also includes numbers (Zahlen), but if you want to say that the *number* of old people is growing (as opposed to the old people themselves), you can not omit "Zahl" - because that is what is growing. So if you want to use "Vergrößerung", it would have to be

> Die Alterungswelle ist ein Begriff, der bedeutet, dass es eine starke Vergrößerung der Zahl von Alten in der Gesellschaft geben wird.

A word with the same sense that you could use with "an" would be "Zuwachs", because that always refers to the number or the amount of something:

> Die Alterungswelle ist ein Begriff, der bedeutet, dass es einen starken Zuwachs an  Alten in der Gesellschaft geben wird.

Now to the usage of an article with "an":

As you know, the German language has "bestimmte" (definite) and "unbestimmte" (indefinite) articles.

Definite articles (der, die, das) exist in both singular and plural form.

The singular indefinite article is "ein" or "eine", and the plural is *no article*:

Singular:

> **Eine Pflanze** braucht Wasser und Licht.
> Diese Rose hat **eine Blüte**.

Plural:

> **Pflanzen** brauchen Wasser und Licht.
> Dieser Baum hat **Blüten**.

This is also the reason why "an" is without article in this case -- because it is about indefinite old people:

> Es wird einen starken Zuwachs an Alten in der Gesellschaft geben.

Moreover, there's also uncountable words: these are singular, but also go without article (for a whole different reason):

> Es wird einen starken Zuwachs an Gewinn geben.

Note that "an" is used in a specific way in these examples, to define a group of people or things, which can only be uncountable or plural.

For other uses of "an", the definite article is fine:

> Sein Verhalten nach der Wahl war ein Verrat an der Demokratie.
> Sie sitzt am Fenster.

Answer (score 0):

> Es gibt **eine** große Auswahl an Angeboten.

> ..**eine** Vergrößerung/Erhöhung an Kranken..

Another reason why that occures is absence of indefinte Articles in plural:

> - Der Mann lehnt sich an die Wand.
> - Der Mann lehnt sich an die Wände.
> - Der Mann lehnt sich an eine Wand.
> - Der Mann lehnt sich an () Wände.

or

> - Ich warte oft an dem Bahnhof.
> - Ich warte oft an den Bahnhöfen.
> - Ich warte oft an einem Bahnhof.
> - Ich warte oft an () Bahnhöfen.

or

> - Ich fahre an diesem Weihnachten weg.
> - Ich fahre an diesen Weihnachten (plural) weg.
> - Ich fahre an einem Weihnachten weg. (semantically wrong)
> - Ich fahre an () Weihnachten weg.

(german source: https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/372)

OffTopic:

> Die Alterungswelle ist ein Begriff, der bedeutet, dass es eine starke **Erhöhung** an Alten in der Gesellschaft geben wird.

In my opinion is "Vergrößerung" not used in the context of numbers and figures..